# Multiplication Table Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: c#, multiplication

I have to write a code to make a 10x10 multiplication table and its display must look like this:

[image]

However, I can't figure out how to display my code correctly. Here is my code below. I know I'm close, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
/*
 * This program displays a multiplication table of the product of every integer from 1 through 10
 * multiplied by every integer from 1 through 10.
 * 
 */


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DisplayMultiplicationTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int value = 10;

            for (int x = 1; x <= value; ++x)

                Console.Write("{0, 4}", x);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________");

            for (int x = 1; x <= value; ++x)

                Console.WriteLine("{0, 4}", x);

            for (int row = 1; row <= value; ++row)
            {
                for (int column = 1; column <= value; ++column)
                {

                    Console.Write("{0, 4}", row * column);

                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe what is wrong about the display generated by the code above?

Comment: his display is not as expected!

Comment: The second for loop prints out 1-10 on new lines, then he prints his table below.  Just needs to rearrange the row header writes.

Answer (score 1):

Added :

```
Console.Write("{0, 4}", row);
```

after start of the `row` for statement

Fixed Code :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = 10;

        Console.Write("    ");
        for (int x = 1; x <= value; ++x)
            Console.Write("{0, 4}", x);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("_____________________________________________");

        for (int row = 1; row <= value; ++row)
        {
            Console.Write("{0, 4}", row);
            for (int column = 1; column <= value; ++column)
            {
                Console.Write("{0, 4}", row * column);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Result :

[image: display]

Comment: Like the list of values above the line, I also need 1-10 running from top to bottom as the first column. Like a multiplication table.

Comment: @AppDeveloper, you orignal answer was missing a whole set of numbers, I see you have fixed it so I reversed the downvote

Answer (score 1):

```
    int value = 10;

    // Indent column headers
    Console.Write("{0, 4}", null);

    // Write column headers
    for (int x = 1; x <= value; ++x)
        Console.Write("{0, 4}", x);

    // Write column header seperator
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("_____________________________________________");

    // Write the table
    for (int row = 1; row <= value; ++row)
    {
        // Write the row header
        Console.Write("{0, 4}", row);

        for (int column = 1; column <= value; ++column)
        {
            // Write the row values
            Console.Write("{0, 4}", row * column);
        }
        // Finish the line
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```

[image]